# Why is this code not giving me custom enumerations in ConTeXt?

Tags: enumerate, context

I am trying to make some enumerated items in ConTeXt appear with a small section of underline, instead of the bullet point. Here is my attempt, but no matter how many combinations I try, I cannot get this to work:

```
\definesymbol[bigunderline][{___}]

\define[1]\matchtheletters{%
    \startitemize[symbol=bigunderline]
    #1
    \stopitemize
}%

\starttext

    \matchtheletters{
    
        \item try it out
        
    }

\stoptex
```

How do I get it to show the underscores instead of bullet points for the items?

Comment: The reason why your solution doesn't work is that ConTeXt sets the symbol before the argument you pass to `\startitemize` is parsed. A way to enable a custom symbol with `\startitemize` is to include the name of the symbol in the list of `keywords`, e.g. `\startitemize[bigunderline]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want to do, but I suggest to define your own itemgroup. Also, to use three underscores to make the symbol might be questionable. Here is a suggestion, but feel free to clarify your question in case I misunderstand something.

```
% \definesymbol[bigunderline][___]
\definesymbol[bigunderline][{\blackrule[width=2em,height=0pt,depth=0.5pt]}]

\defineitemgroup[bigunderlinelist]
\setupitemgroup[bigunderlinelist][symbol=bigunderline,width=3em]

\starttext

\startbigunderlinelist
\item A first item.
\item \samplefile{tufte}
\item Yet another item.
\stopbigunderlinelist

\stoptext
```

[image: list with bars]